# Adding a new node to a list and dynamically naming it

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I have a few questions regarding lists. First, here is my code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int x;
    node *next;
};

void main()
{
    node *root;
    node *curr;

    int exit = 0;
    string temp;
    root = new node;
    root->next = 0;
    curr = root;
    cout << "Please enter the root number: ";
    cin >> root->x;

    for( int i=0; i<10; i++)//Will promt user to enter numbers
    {
        cout << "Enter string name for new node: ";
        cin >> temp;
    }

    if (curr != 0)//Used for traversing the LL and outputting
    {
        while (curr->next != 0)
        {
            cout << curr->x;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the user to be prompted to enter a number in the for loop to be added on to the first node. But I am confused on creating more nodes past the root. Do they have to have different names for each node? I see where I created a new node named root. Would I have to do that for each and every node? If I do, can I have the user input a name for that node and have the program write in that name?

Comment: On each iteration, you have to create a new node, point root to it, and point its next to the former root.

Comment: But how would creating the new node go? Do I have to create a name for it like root?

Comment: Is this a class assignment? Anyone who's trying to teach you node-based collections and manual memory management before teaching the basics of variables shouldn't be a teacher…

Comment: No, not a class assignment. Learning this on my own. I know the basics of variables.

Comment: If you know the basics of variables, why do you think you need a new one for each node?

Comment: Because variables are different than nodes. My struct acts like a class in that it stores data, whereas the only variable assigned is root. I was simply wondering if I needed a new variable (like root) for each node. But I was simply not fully grasping the concept of a linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create more nodes past the root, just do the same thing:

```
 // assuming 'curr' points to end of list
 curr->next = new node;  // here's the new node
 curr = curr->next;      // update curr (if you want) to point to the newest node
 curr->next = 0;         // probably should be done in nodes ctor
```

You would not "name" the new nodes, you just have "root" and "curr". To find any one node, start at "root" and traverse to the one you want. Of course you could save ptrs to some nodes for faster access, but that would be specific to a particular application.

Also in your current input loop:

```
for( int i=0; i<10; i++)//Will promt user to enter numbers
{
    cout << "Enter string name for new node: ";
    cin >> temp;
}
```

The user inputs a value 10 times, but it goes in 'temp' every time. So it keeps getting overwritten.

Comment: The for loop is currently under construction ;) Thank you for your reply it helps greatly! I simply just didnt know if I had to name the new nodes or not. Thank you!

Comment: One more thing, in the last loop, when I want to output do I need to set curr back to root?

Comment: @Nogg Yes. anytime you "walk" a linked list you generally start at `root`. Set `curr=root` **immediatley** before you begin the walk. As originally written it would only walk one node, then exit.

Comment: For some reason when I do that, it won't print the root.

Comment: If as @WhozCraig says, you set curr=root and then start traversing with "while curr->next !=0" it will print the root. I wonder if you're seeing something else? Maybe you loop once before the first print? Maybe "root" is actually pointing to 2nd entry?